# What is the standard way to train a PyTorch script until convergence?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

what is the standard way to detect if a model has converged? I was going to record 5 losses with 95 confidence intervals each loss and if they all agreed then I’d halt the script. I assume training until convergence must be implemented already in PyTorch or PyTorch Lightning somewhere. I don’t need a perfect solution, just the standard way to do this automatically - i.e. halt when converged.

My solution is easy to implement. Once create a criterion and changes the reduction to `none`. Then it will output a tensor of size `[B]`. Every you log you record that and it's 95 confidence interval (or std if you prefer, but that is much less accuracy). Then every time you add a new loss with it's confidence interval make sure it remains of size 5 (or 10) and that the 5 losses are within a 95 CI of each other. Then if that is true halt.

You can compute the CI with this:

```
def torch_compute_confidence_interval(data: Tensor,
                                           confidence: float = 0.95
                                           ) -> Tensor:
    """
    Computes the confidence interval for a given survey of a data set.
    """
    n = len(data)
    mean: Tensor = data.mean()
    # se: Tensor = scipy.stats.sem(data)  # compute standard error
    # se, mean: Tensor = torch.std_mean(data, unbiased=True)  # compute standard error
    se: Tensor = data.std(unbiased=True) / (n**0.5)
    t_p: float = float(scipy.stats.t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2., n - 1))
    ci = t_p * se
    return mean, ci
```

and you can create the criterion as follow:

```
loss: nn.Module = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
```

so the train loss is now of size `[B]`.

---

note that I know how to train with a fixed number of epochs, so I am not really looking for that - just the halting criterion for when to stop when models looks converged, what a person would sort of do when they look at their learning curve but automatically.

---

ref:
https://forums.pytorchlightning.ai/t/what-is-the-standard-way-to-halt-a-script-when-it-has-converged/1415

Comment: what can be done is something similar to what pytorch lightning does with early stopping. If what I truly want to do is stop when convergence, then halt once the train loss stops decreasing (e.g. after 5 log steps). Since a log step is 1 epoch or say 150 iterations, if it stops improving after 5 steps it's likely your model is done training. No need to compute confidence intervals. Simpler!

Comment: Note that I am usually checkpointing the "best validation model" so this is very similar to stopping at early stopping. But if you want to truly do early stopping do the same as above but wrt validation loss.

Answer (score 1):

Set an EarlyStopping (https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.EarlyStopping.html#pytorch_lightning.callbacks.EarlyStopping) callback in your trainer by

```py
checkpoint_callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(
        monitor="val_f1_score",
        min_delta=0.01,
        patience=10,  # NOTE no. val epochs, not train epochs
        verbose=False,
        mode="min",
    ),
]

trainer = pl.Trainer(callbacks=callbacks)
```

This will monitor changes in `val_f1_score` during training (notice that you have to log this value with `self.log("val_f1_score", val_f1)`  in your `pl.LightningModule`). It will stop the training if the minimum change to quantity to qualify as an improvement (`min_delta`) for more than the number of epoch specified as `patience`